# Does Windows 10 log network activity?

Tags: windows, privacy, logging, windows-10

I've been thinking a lot about private browsing recently. Here's a scenario I've been thinking about:

Let's say I have a browser installed on my Windows 10 PC called "ChromeFox" (made up, it's just an example). ChromeFox is a "private" browser, it does not store any browsing-related data on my PC.

In such a scenario, does Windows 10 itself log any data pertaining to the my browsing activity on ChromeFox? Any DNS requests, domains/IPs I've visited, maybe even the specific webpages I've seen? (etc etc)

If the answer to this question is "yes", where are these logs kept?